# Rails app refreshing on localhost - event.returnValue is deprecated warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails app on localhost started randomly refreshing when using the 'back' browser arrow. Chrome(31.0.1650.48) console reads:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

I guess these issues are connected.

I also found [this recent issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320) on jQuery bugtracker. Funny thing, but 10 hours ago everything was fine.

Anyone experiencing similar problems? What are the options?

EDIT: although I was browsing my app on localhost, I found out that a number of production websites are experiencing the same problem, showing the same console output, including [37signals](https://37signals.com/svn/posts/3651-remote-works-bebanjo-spain)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is largely due to the newest version of Chrome that you are using.  I haven't found the exact details but it appears that Chrome has decided to deprecate this property which is currently used by jQuery.

Since it's just a deprecation, nothing will be broken yet, but it does mean that it will be removed in the future.  Once jQuery fixes the issue you should probably try to update.

Edit: Sorry I missed the point - I would assume that the random refreshing is unrelated to the message you are seeing about `event.returnValue`

Comment: Actually I believe you're right, but I will do some testing before accepting. Safari works fine and shows no warnings. Refreshing happens when you press the Back button in Chrome to return to a page that has jQuery. I suggest you it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out Looks like the native js method 'event.returnValue' has been marked as deprecated in newer Chrome versions. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320